# Crontab not executing

Tags: centos, cron, time

I'm running CentOS 6.2, trying to run tasks through cron. I've verified `crond` is running

```
$ service crond status
crond (pid  20553) is running...
```

I have no `/etc/cron.allow` file, but I do have an `/etc/cron.deny` file that is empty.

I've checked the `/var/log/cron` file only to find entries of `EDIT` and `RELOAD` sessions, nothing being executed.

I did have some trouble with my system clock earlier today, and I think I resolved it. `$ date` and `$ uptime` both give back the correct time, but I can't execute `hwclock` commands for other issues. Should I look into problems with the hardware clock as the cause for nothing being executed or is there something else I'm forgetting here?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: The problem was that I wasn't sure if my tasks were running at all. I couldn't figure out a decent way to output things from my commands. Turns out my paths were just funky. Any quick tips on outputting crontab stderr?

Answer (score -1):

Turns out my problem was just a misnamed path to my commands. I couldn't figure out a decent way to output stderr for cron tasks. Once I got that working, I found my tasks were indeed running, just failing.